# Set default values of a column in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server database and want to set a default value to a column of a table

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id = '5' THEN sid ELSE '0' END) AS 'total'
FROM records
```

I want to set a default value to 0 if this query is not returning anything.

Comment: I think you mean a value for your query when returned value is null? Not a default value for your table. Adding a default to a table column is something quite different.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN sid END) As total
FROM records
```

Will *always* return exactly one row.  The value will be `0` if there are no rows that match the conditions.  `COUNT()` does not return `NULL`; it returns `0`.

Note that `id` is presumably a number so I dropped the the single quotes.  The `ELSE` clause did not make sense to make.  I think it makes more sense to ignore values when `id <> 5`.

This particular query would probably be better written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sid) As total
FROM records
WHERE id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```sql
SELECT
   COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id = '5' THEN sid ELSE '0' END),0) AS 'total'
FROM records
```

or

```sql
SELECT
   ISNULL((COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id = '5' THEN sid ELSE '0' END),0) AS 'total'
FROM records
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).